# Python not picking a random from list

Tags: random, python-3.x

I currently use python 3.3.2 and am making a text based game. I am trying to get the game to pick a random  when you attack. This is the part of the code affected

```
        # North hand in hole
        if hand_in_hole == "Y":
           print ("Inside you brush aside cobwebs that must of not been moved in years. Sudenly somthing move against your skin. Do you remove your hand from the hole? Y/N")
           keep_handin_hole = input()
           #North/hand in hole/keep it in
           if keep_handin_hole == "N":
               print ("A huge spider as large as your fist crawls up your arm. Do you attack it? Y/N")
               attack_spider = input
               #North/hand in hole/keep it in/attack
               if attack_spider == "Y":
                   attack = ['Miss', 'Miss', 'Miss', 'Miss', 'Hit']
                   from random import choice
                   print (choice(attack))
```

When I run this I get:

```
    You must answer all questions in block capitals
    Welcome to maze runner are you ready Y/N?
    Y
    Chose your Name
    Callum
    Well hello Callum You find yourself in a deep dark maze you must escape before the beast      get's you. Are you still ready for the challange? Y/N
    Y
    You find yourself in the middle of the maze with four exits? NORTH/SOUTH/EAST/WEST
    NORTH
    There is a hole in the middle of the wall. Do you put your hand in? Y/N
    Y
    Inside you brush aside cobwebs that must of not been moved in years. Sudenly somthing move against your skin. Do you remove your hand from the hole? Y/N
    N
    A huge spider as large as your fist crawls up your arm. Do you attack it? Y/N
    >>>
```

It never gets to picking a random why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing parentheses on the second `input()`. The line `attack_spider = input` merely assigns the input function to a new name rather than actually calling the function. Also, you probably want to use `raw_input()`, because `input()` evaluates the given expression, and you just want strings.

Comment: Is it possible to make it possible like if it equals miss it says "your attack my the spider angry